# how function handler function handler work in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to understand how is this code works

```
$("#imageGallery a").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Why is the function handler (in this case "event") are executed? Isn't the handler supposed to be some var which isn't executed? *feel free to share any keyword / article about this*

Thankss..

Comment: Read how it works, http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.click()` method as you are using it takes an argument which is a callback function.

```
$("#imageGallery a").click(myCallback);

function myCallback(e) {
    // the argument e which you can name anything you want is a
    // jQuery event object
}
```

That callback function will be passed a single argument which is a jQuery event object.  I've written the code above to use a separately defined function for the callback for illustration purposes.  But, the function can also be defined inline as an inline anonymous function like this:

```
$("#imageGallery a").click(function(e) {
    // the argument e is a jQuery event object
});
```

The jQuery event object has both properties and methods.  `.preventDefault()` is one of the methods on that object.  You can see a list of other properties on the object [here in the jQuery doc](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation ifriend, I understand it now. And just wondering, how computer identify that inside the ( ) is JQuery event object or an object ?

Comment: It is part of the documentation for `.click()`.  The caller of the callback determines the arguments for the callback.  In this case, the caller of the callback is the `.click()` jQuery code so you look in the jQuery doc for `.click()` to see what arguments it sends the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

`event` is not an *event handler*, it is an *event object* with properties and methods, including `preventDefault()` method that is being called in your example.

Your *event handler* is an anonymous function `function(event){ event.preventDefault(); }`

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `event` (The first argument passed to your function) contains an object of the event that happened (In this case a click event). That event object creates functions such as `preventDefault()`, which tell the browser to ignore any future action from this event, such as opening the link that was clicked.

Try adding a line right before it:

```
$("#imageGallery a").click(function(event){
  console.log(event);
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

And take a look at your console (Press F12), and look as the console tab, and see what it outputs. You can see all the fields, and everything else that the `event` object contains.

To clarify things a bit more, `event` is not a handler, your entire function is:

```
function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

jQuery will then pass the browser event object to this function when the event is fired, and your code will then execute.